# 'expire' and 'file_cache' mods are 'enabled' but will not show in mod list nor works in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

It is a Ubunto 16.04 64bit LAMP server. I have enabled Cache header with

```
sudo a2enmod file_cache
```

and expire header with

```
sudo a2enmod expires
```

Then I restarted Apache server with
 service apache2 restart
but those mods are not showing in

```
/usr/sbin/apache2 -l
```

Output:

```
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_so.c
  mod_watchdog.c
  http_core.c
  mod_log_config.c
  mod_logio.c
  mod_version.c
  mod_unixd.c
```

and lavarage caching in .htaccess is not working either.
Tried this expire headers,

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 15 days"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType text/js "access plus 1 months"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 months"
</IfModule>
```

The response header is

```
Response headers (317 B)    
Cache-Control   
max-age=1296000
CF-RAY  
43dff56b31ff70b6-SIN
Connection  
keep-alive
Content-Encoding    
gzip
Content-Type    
text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    
Sat, 21 Jul 2018 19:08:52 GMT
Expires 
Sun, 05 Aug 2018 19:11:07 GMT
Server  
cloudflare
Transfer-Encoding   
chunked
Vary    
Accept-Encoding
```

Edit: Cloudflare(free plan) is enabled with default settings.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Cloudflare cache your website content, try flushing cache from cloudflare admin panel if you are using cloudflare as proxy.

Comment: I will try it and let you know the result. Any idea why those 2 mods are not showing in modlist?